# Reactjs, semantic ui react, menu>item problems

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

This is my first question here and I'm a beginner to React app and semantic ui react, so sorry if my question is a little nooby.

So i created a menu using semantic ui react using  after importing it. 
Now I have an option to choose any background color for the menu among the given choices. But i want to set it to a custom color. So how do I target it in an override style sheet? I tried .ui.menu and failed. Here's the starting part of the code:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react'
import { Input, Menu, Image, Grid, Sticky } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Link from 'next/link';
import { relative } from 'path';

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    state = { activeItem: this.props.currentPage }
    contextRef = createRef()
    render() {
        const { activeItem } = this.state
        return (
            <div >
                <Menu size="massive" className="size" pointing stackable>
                    <Image style={{ 'font-size': 50 }} avatar src='http://www.transitionsta.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/twitter-black-round-icon.png' className='logo' />
                        <Link href='/home'>
                            <Wrap>
                               <Menu.Item
                                  name='HOME'
                                  active={activeItem === 'home'}
                                  position='right'
                                   />
                             </Wrap>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href="/contact">
                              <Wrap>
                                  <Menu.Item
                                     name='CONTACT US'
                                     active={activeItem === 'contact us'}
                                     position='right'
                                    />
                                </Wrap>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href='/aboutProfile'>
                             <Wrap>
                              <Menu.Item
                                 name='ABOUT US'
                                 active={activeItem === 'about us'}
                                 position='right'
                                 />
                                </Wrap>
                            </Link>
                </Menu>
```

So how would targeting Menu background color be done and how exactly would it differ from targetting a menu>item? 
Thanks guys.

Comment: Hi Shashank and welcome to SO. Inspect your app and see what class your menu items have and target them that way ? Or simply add a class to your menu items with `className=".."` ? I hope I understood what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- a className attribute (making sure it overrides current CSS, make use of `!important` when needed)
- a inline style `<Menu style={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}}>`
- [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I used the styled components and it works. But I still can't target the exact classname. I tried .ui.menu.item{} and other things but it did not work. So could help me out by telling the exact className? Also, inline style doesn't work on <Menu.Item> Apparently its not targetting the background color for some reason.

Comment: There are rules about CSS classname priority, one of those is "more specific CSS path wins", do you have an online demo to determine the exact CSS path to override ? If parent css does non have an `!important` flag, you can use it in your CSS class definition in order to take precedence over a more specific CSS path

Comment: In the semantic.css file, the file which is being imported, almost all tags have a !important added to it. :/

Comment: Hi, so I just updated the post with pretty much the whole code. So to get to the menu item, there is a div, then a <Menu> a <Link>, a <Wrap> and then there's the <Menu Item> which i want to modify. So how would i do that? Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate the support.

Comment: If you select the element with chrome inspector tool under tab "elements", at the very bottom of the inspector you can see the most specific path to reach that element in your scaffolding (you component scaffolding is itself in another HTML scaffolding, in order to be served to a browser) using full path with elements (IE: "div") and classes/ID will give you a pattern lilke "body div.wrapper div.menu div .item" or something similar. Use this path to setup your override and it should be fine. As said can also use the !important keyword at the end of the CSS rule. In this case "last rule wins"